# how to plot coef plot in lasso with each k fold validation?

Tags: python, lasso-regression

I am trying to plot the coef plot i.e. variable importance plot with each k-fold validation iteration. I don't know how to do it, for a single run I can get a variable plot using a `lasso.coef` command, but not able to plot variation in importance variable with each fold.

[image]

This is the plot I got using lasso, now I want this graph for all k-fold iterations.

```
lasso = Lasso(alpha=0.001)
model = lasso.fit(X_train,Y_train)


score2 = model.coef_
importance = pd.Series(score2, colname)
importance.nlargest(35).plot(kind='barh')

train_score = lasso.score(X_train, Y_train)
test_score = lasso.score(X_test, Y_test)

print("training score: ", train_score)
print("test score: ", test_score)


coef = lasso.coef_


importance = pd.Series(coef, colname)
importance.nlargest(35).plot(kind='barh')


#Step6: k fold validation
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


cvlasso=Lasso(alpha=0.001)
score = cross_val_score(cvlasso,X_train,Y_train,cv=10)

#cvlasso.fit(X,Y)

print(score)
print(np.mean(score))
```

This is the loop for plotting the variable.

```
cvlasso=Lasso(alpha=0.001)
score = cross_val_score(cv=10)

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf =KFold(n_splits=10)
cvlasso= Lasso(alpha=0.001)
count = 1

for X_train, _ in kf.split(X, Y):
    cvlasso.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    importances_index_desc = np.argsort(cvlasso.feature_importances_)[::-1]
    feature_labels = list(X.columns.values)
    # plot
    plt.figure()
    plt.bar(feature_labels, cvlasso.feature_importances_[importances_index_desc])
    plt.xticks(feature_labels, rotation='vertical')
    plt.ylabel('Importance')
    plt.xlabel('Features')
    plt.title('Fold {}'.format(count))
    count = count + 1
plt.show()
```

Comment: provide working example

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I updated the code please check again.